# How to refine this code and sort the data being read into the array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to write a C program to read an array, calculate the sum of all individual entries, the average, the minimum grade, the maximum grade, and print all of those values. Is this an effective method of sorting? I'm attempting to sort the data values by min and max comparing it as they are input. My compiler also throws a declaration error with all of the float values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
float main()

int i;
float grades[10];
float grade;
float sum;
float avg;
float count;
float max;
float min;

{
max =0;
min=0;

printf("Enter your grades (Type <0 and >100 to quit): ");
scanf("%f", &grade);

sum=0;
i=0;
while(grades>0 && i<10)
{grades[i]= grade;
i++;
if(i<10)
{printf("Enter grade, (Type <0 or >100 to quit): ");
scanf("%f", &grade); }}
for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
{if (grades[i] > max)
            {
                max=grades[i];
            }
            else if (grades[i] < min)
            {
                min = grades[i];
            }}

            count=i;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        {printf("Grade %d is %f \n", i+1, grades[i]);}
        grade=0;
    for(i=0;i<count; i++)
    {sum= sum + grades[i];}
    if(count>0)
    {avg=sum/count;}
        else
        {avg=0;}
printf("The average of the %f grades is %f \n",count, avg);
printf("The Minimum Grade is %f",min);
printf("The Maximum Grade is %f", max);
printf("Count is %f ", count);
printf("Sum is %f", sum);
printf("Average is %f", avg);
}
```

Comment: Assuming the grades are all positive and if no one gets `0` then your code will not get the correct `min` value as your initial `min` value is already `0` (the smallest valid value).

Comment: Do you have a *specific* problem? Does your code work as it is now? You mention a declaration error, but you don't show the *exact* error as it comes out of the compiler.

Comment: `float main()` should be `int main()`; main should always returns an int, never a float. You would also want to declare your variables *inside* the main body, not between the `main()` declaration and the body.

Comment: Please edit your post and indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

The very refided code for solving your problem is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

#define GRADE_ARRAY_LEN 10

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    double grades[GRADE_ARRAY_LEN];
    double grade;
    double max;
    double min;

    while(i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN)
    {
        printf("Enter grade, (Type <0 or >100 to quit): ");
        if(scanf("%lf", &grade) != 1)
        {
            printf("The value entered could not be converted to double. Please enter another value.\n");
            scanf("%s");
            continue;
        }
        if(grade < 0.0 || grade > 100.0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                max = grade;
                min = grade;
            }
            else
            {
                if(grade > max)
                {
                    max = grade;
                }
                if(grade < min)
                {
                    min = grade;
                }
            }
            grades[i]= grade;
            i++;
        }
    }

    double sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN; i++)
    {
        printf("Grade %d is %lg \n", i+1, grades[i]);
        sum+=grades[i];
    }

    double avg = sum/GRADE_ARRAY_LEN;

    printf("The average of the %d grades is %g \n", GRADE_ARRAY_LEN, avg);
    printf("The Minimum Grade is %lg\n",min);
    printf("The Maximum Grade is %lg\n", max);
    printf("Number of grades is %d\n", GRADE_ARRAY_LEN);
    printf("Sum is %lg\n", sum);
    printf("Average is %lg\n", avg);
    return 0;
}
```

I may have missed something, but i checked it and it works.
The - How it works is a bit long.

First of all the amount of grades you want to enter is fixed and defined in `#define GRADE_ARRAY_LEN 10` which lets you easily change the number of grades you want to enter.

Then the programm reads input and checks if the input is double or can be converted to double. This check is simple `if(scanf("%lf", &grade) != 1)`. `scanf()` returns the number of arguments successfully filled, the format "%lf" means that you want your input argument to be filled as double. So `scanf("%lf", &grade)` will return only return a value which equals to 1, if you entered a value that can be converted to double.

Now if the input IS NOT double or double or can be converted to double the program askes you to enter an input which is double or can be converted to double. `scanf("%s");` is actully needed because when `scanf("%lf", &grade)` fails there is a newline char left in the input stream, which you have to actually read. If you don't, next `scanf("%lf", &grade)` will actually take it as an input, and fail again, thus creating an infinite loop.

After the input is successfully filled, it means you have your value of grade. The program checks what value was entered, and exits if the value is smaller than 0 or greater than 100. I did this because printf actually outputs, that the program will exit if the value is smaller than 0 or greater than 100.

If  the value of grade is between 0 and 100, then the program checks if it is the first value that was scanned with this `if(i == 0)`. Where i is the number of successfully scanned values. If i == 0 than no values were scanned yet, so max and min must be initialized with this value for max and min to work correctly., because all other values have to be checked against the first value. If i != 0, then the value is checked against max an min, and they are modified in case of need.

After min and max are checked the value is FINALLY added to our array of values and the number of successfully scanned values is increased.

```
i++;grades[i]= grade;
i++;
```

NOTE!!!: all the operations above are commited in one single loop, `while(i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN)`. This ensures that you enter the correct amount of values and get the correct max and min values. You do not actually need extra loops to get correct min and max values.

After the loop, the `sum` of grades is counted. After that, the `avg` of grades is counted.

NOTE!!!: You do not need any checks here because the loop ensures that you enter correct amount of elemets.

In the end the results are printed to a command line.

I'll try to point out the main parts that i edited.

First: variable declarations must be inside the brakets of `main()` and main must return an int, which means your code had this:

```
float main()

int i;
float grades[10];
float grade;
float sum;
float avg;
float count;
float max;
float min;

{
```

but it must be like this

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    double grades[GRADE_ARRAY_LEN];
    double grade;
    double max;
    double min;
```

Second: Your code did not check if `scanf("%lf", &grade)` successfully filled `grade`. That is wrong because you can actually enter any combination of characters and numbers in command line, but the only correct input is when you enter a number, that can be converted to double. That means you have to check what scanf returns.

Third: `max = 0; and min = 0;` is not the correct way to initialize max and min values. `min=0;` is incorrect, because in case of only positive grades, grade will never be smaller than min, thus min will be always 0. The correct way is to initialize min value is with  the first correctly read grade from input, so if there is a smaller value is entered, then min can be changed accordinly. The `max=0;` is incorrect because in case of only negative grades, grade will never be greater than max, thus max will be always 0. The correct way is to initialize max value is with the first correctly read grade from input, so if there is a greater value is entered, then max can be changed accordinly.

Third: As i said above, you do not actually need a separate loop to find max and min values. It can be done inside the loop where data is read. It is not really nececcary, but it's a good practice to do everything you can inside one loop.

Fourth: It is a good practice to define lenght of arrays with fixed length before main function using `#define`. Quote: "The #define creates a macro, which is the association of an identifier or parameterized identifier with a token string. After the macro is defined, the compiler can substitute the token string for each occurrence of the identifier in the source file.". That basically means that you add `#define GRADE_ARRAY_LEN 10`, as shown in code above, before main, and then instead of using 10 as the number of iterations, and number of array elements like `double grades[10]; while(i<10); for(i=0;i<10;i++)`
you actually use `double grades[GRADE_ARRAY_LEN]; while(i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN); for(i=0;i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN;i++)`. The compiler will automaticly substitute GRADE_ARRAY_LEN for 10; Thsi enables you to change 10 for any other number you want (positive of course) only in one place, instead of changing it in several places;

Fifth: `printf("Enter grade, (Type <0 or >100 to quit): ")` outputs that if you type a value <0 or >100 the program should exit. Considering the input values were not checked at all, this is not happening.

Sixth: while(grades>0 && i<10) is wrong, because grades is an Array, and you can not compare an array to a single number.

Now on to what i actually did to the code to make it work:

1) Moved the var declarations and changed the return value of main

2) Implemented a check for successfull filling of grade by `scanf("%lf", &grade)`.

3) Implemented a program exit in case if input is <0 or >100;. This means the program will actuallly exit if you enter a number smaller than 0 and greater than 100

4) Implemented a `#define GRADE_ARRAY_LEN` 10 to use as a length of grade array

5) Re-made the loop so it will ask to enter correct input data GRADE_ARRAY_LEN times. Now the program won't continue unless you enter correct input data exactly GRADE_ARRAY_LEN times.

6) Moved the finding of `min` and `max` values to the while loop. As said above, you do not actually need a separate loop to find them. Also modified the initialization of min and max

7) Due to changes above, made some changes in the end.

7.1) Changed a little the way `sum` is counted
Was:

```
 for(i=0;i<count; i++)
    {sum= sum + grades[i];}
```

Now:

```
double sum = 0;
for(i=0; i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN; i++)
{
    printf("Grade %d is %lg \n", i+1, grades[i]);
    sum+=grades[i];
}
```

7.2) Removed unnecessary check upon calculating `avg`
Was:

```
if(count>0)
    {avg=sum/count;}
        else
        {avg=0;}
```

Now:

```
double avg = sum/GRADE_ARRAY_LEN;
```

8) Changed all float values to double. The amount of bytes float allocates for a var is actually dependant on system architecture, where double is actually an Quote: "IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64".

9) Due to changes above, changed format of the input data from %f to %lf, Changed format of output data from %f to %lg. Now both can work with double.

Comment: code only answes are not very helpful to either the OP or future visitors, please expand a little on what you did and why you think this works.

Comment: surely you will have thought something while programming it, surely you found the mistakes OP made. Writing that down and going into more detail improves your answer siginificantly.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've now explained *how* your code works, not *why* it works, compared to the OP's code. What the *essential* differences and corrections you made.

Comment: I more hellishly long edit. I will edit it once more in the evening only, if no one edits it before, and try to make an answer to - Why it works, and more to the point - Why it works correctly, more clear

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Keep in mind we don't mean to diminish your work or insult you, our comments are just pointers towards making your answer more usable and better for everyone. I didn't downvote, by the way.

Comment: Beleave me, I am not offended or insulted. I don't actually care about who downvoted. I look at the comments and try to improve my anwswer step by step). I know that my explaning sucks))). It's actually nice to know where is sucks and why it sucks. It helpes to improve. I wouln'd mind if someone even helped with editing the explanation. I am pretty sure someone can write it far better than me. I am more of a coder.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this:

```
double min;

while(i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN)
{
.......

printf("The value entered could not be converted to double. Please enter another value.\n");

scanf("%s");
```

With this:

```
double min;
char c;

while(i<GRADE_ARRAY_LEN)
{
.......
        printf("The value entered could not be converted to double. Please enter another value.\n");
        scanf("%s", &c);
```

Should fix the scanf error. The second error is probably because you forgot to copy the closing braket - "}" of main at the very end. What i mean is that you probably have this at the very end:

```
printf("Average is %lg\n", avg);
return 0;
```

But!!! it shold be like this

```
  printf("Average is %lg\n", avg);
  return 0;  
} // !!!!
```